# javascript regex to match a string ends with particular word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two strings 
`"track/bugfix merged to 'master'"`
`"track/bugfix merged to 'track/clonemaster'"`

I want regex to match string ends with `'master'` only
can anyone help me on this?

Comment: `testString.match(/master'$/gi)`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn it matches both the strings

Comment: I think your `i want regex to match...` line is wrong you have `master'`, you mean `'master'` correct?

Comment: If so, you want `testString.match(/'master'$/gi)`

Comment: cool yeah it works thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the end of a string, use the [`$`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) anchor, this signifies the end of a line.

So, the regular expression that you are looking for is as follows:

```
/'master'$/gi
```

```js
const matches = [
  "track/bugfix merged to 'master'",
  "track/bugfix merged to 'track/clonemaster'"
].map(testString => !!testString.match(/'master'$/gi))

console.log(matches)
```